How to make conditions work in Which?
How to make Condition convert to common expresstions when it mathes Which test.
ClearAll[v1, v2, vm1, vm2, expr1, expr2, fn]
expr1 = Sqrt[v1 - v2] /; v1 > v2;
expr2 = Sqrt[-v1 + v2] /; v1 < v2;
fn[v1_, v2_] = Module[
   {},
   Which[v1 > v2, expr1, v1 < v2, expr2 ] // Evaluate
   ];
PiecewiseExpand[fn[v1, vm1], v1 > vm1] + 
 PiecewiseExpand[fn[vm2, v2], vm2 < v2]

output
(Sqrt[v1 - v2] /; v1 > v2) + (Sqrt[-v1 + v2] /; v1 < v2)

However, I would expect this one
Sqrt[v1 - vm1] + Sqrt[-vm2 + v2]


The Attributes of Which include HoldAll, so expr1 and expr2 are not evaluated when fn is defined. Check with ? fn to see its ultimate definition. They need to be Evaluate-d, too. Another way is to turn them into functions (expr[v1_, v2] =....).

Condition is usually used together with patterns, not as a part of algebraic expressions. PiecewiseExpand doesn't seem to resolve Condition, but FullSimplify does:
PiecewiseExpand[a /; b > c, b > c]
(* a /; b > c *)

FullSimplify[a /; b > c, b > c]
(* a *)

However, you have another problem there with the scoping and renaming of symbols:
FullSimplify[fn[v1, v2], v1 > v2]
(* Sqrt[v1 - v2] *)

FullSimplify[fn[v1, vm1], v1 > vm1]
(* Sqrt[v1 - v2] /; v1 > v2 *)

Simplify does not see that vm1 became v2 in your expression, and therefore it doesn't know that v1 > vm1 actually means v1 > v2. I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve and why you are using both Condition and Which when one of them is enough. Here are two alternative ways, both of them avoiding Condition and instead using other functions:

Using Which

ClearAll[expr1, expr2, fn]
expr1[v1_, v2_] := Sqrt[v1 - v2];
expr2[v1_, v2_] := Sqrt[-v1 + v2];
fn[v1_, v2_] := Which[v1 > v2, expr1[v1, v2], v1 < v2, expr2[v1, v2]];

FullSimplify[fn[v1, vm1], v1 > vm1] + FullSimplify[fn[vm2, v2], vm2 < v2]
(* Sqrt[v1 - vm1] + Sqrt[v2 - vm2] *)


Using Piecewise

ClearAll[expr, fn]
expr[v1_, v2_] := Piecewise[{{Sqrt[v1 - v2], v1 > v2}, {Sqrt[-v1 + v2], v1 < v2}}];
fn[v1_, v2_] := expr[v1, v2];

FullSimplify[fn[v1, vm1], v1 > vm1] + FullSimplify[fn[vm2, v2], vm2 < v2]
(* Sqrt[v1 - vm1] + Sqrt[v2 - vm2] *)


Interesting. Didn't know Simplify/FullSimplify can simplify Condition.

Your code is very convoluted. Reading between the lines, it seems like you want something rather simple. Maybe you haven't provided enough context, but with what you've provided, why not just do this?
fn[v1_, v2_] := Sqrt[Abs[v1 - v2]];
Simplify[fn[v1, vm1] + fn[vm2, v2], v1 > vm1 && v2 > vm2]
(* Sqrt[v1 - vm1] + Sqrt[v2 - vm2] *)

